# First statement fails to execute even if correct. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the first if statement fail to execute even if the correct words are typed. Is there something I have failed to consider?

EDIT - I've included my question to show the entire code in order for people to understand the problem.

I'm still having trouble with it. I replaced what I did with the .strip() function but it fails to execute. Hopefully uploaded the entire program will help people understand the root of the problem.

```
from random import randint

game_board = []
player_one = {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}
player_two = {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}

colors = {"reset":"\033[00m",
          "red":"\033[91m",
          "green":"\033[92m",
          "yellow":"\033[93m",
          "blue":"\033[94m",
          "pink":"\033[95m",
          "cyan":"\033[96m"
              }


# Building our 5 x 5 board
def build_game_board(board):
    for item in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

def show_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

# Defining ships locations
def load_game(board):
    print("WELCOME TO BATTLESHIP!")
    print("Find and sink the ship!")
    del board[:]
    build_game_board(board)
    print(colors['cyan'])
    show_board(board)
    print(colors['reset'])
    ship_col = randint(1, len(board))
    ship_row = randint(1, len(board[0]))
    return {
        'ship_col': ship_col,
        'ship_row': ship_row,
    }

ship_points = load_game(game_board)


# Players will alternate turns.
def player_turns(total_turns):

    if total_turns % 2 == 0:
        total_turns += 1
        return player_one

    return player_two

# Allows new game to start
def play_again():

    positive = ["yes", "y"] 
    negative = ["no", "n"]

    global ship_points

    while True:
        answer = input("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ").lower().strip()
        if answer in positive:
            ship_points = load_game(game_board)

        elif answer in negative:   
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            exit()

# What will be done with players guesses
def input_check(ship_row, ship_col, player, board):
    guess_col = 0
    guess_row = 0
    while True:
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number only: ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    match = guess_row == ship_row - 1 and guess_col == ship_col - 1
    not_on_game_board = (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4)

    if match:
        player["wins"] += 1
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        print('The current match score is %d : %d (Player1 : Player2)' % (player_one["wins"], player_two["wins"]))
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again()

    elif not match:
        if not_on_game_board:
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X" or board[guess_row][guess_col] == "Y":
            print("You guessed that one already.")


        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            if player == player_one:
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            else:
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "Y"

        print(colors['blue'])
        show_board(game_board)
        print(colors['reset'])

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')
    while (begin != str('start')):
        begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')

    for games in range(3):
        for turns in range(6):

            if player_turns(turns) == player_one:
                # print(ship_points)
                print("Player One")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_one, game_board
                )

            elif player_turns(turns) == player_two:
                print("Player Two")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_two, game_board
                )

            if turns == 5:
                print("The number of turns has ended.")
                print('The current match score is %d : %d (Player1 : Player2)' % (player_one["wins"], player_two["wins"]))
                play_again()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I've tried it and it actually works for me. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Strinnityk, +1, can you specify why is not working? what is the error you have? or the miss function?

Comment: If I was to type 'yes', 'y', 'Y', or 'YES' the message '("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ")' just keeps appearing and game board does not reload.

Comment: We can't know what is happening unless you post your load_game function. Have you tried setting a `break` below the `load_game` call?

Comment: the load_game function works. It's just that the first if statement does not follow through.

Comment: I've replaced your `load_game` call for a `print` and every time I input `y` or `yes` it calls `print`.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding you wrong. You mean that if you input `y` or `yes` the code inside the if statement doesn't get executed?

Comment: @Strinnityk On some platforms, the final newline is included in the string returned by `input()`, which is the reason why it's not working for the OP, while it's working fine for you.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Oh, thank you for your insight, that hadn't happened to me before. Good to know.

Comment: @Strinnityk Still does not work. I edited the question to hopefully allow people to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
positive = ["yes", "y"] 
negative = ["no", "n"]

while True:
    answer = input("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ").lower().strip()

    if answer in positive:
        ship_points = load_game(game_board)
        break
    elif answer in negative:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()
```

Your positive and negative lists are both lowercase, so it is best to first lowercase any user answer, and also strip off any extra spaces or newline characters.

As your code is inside your `play_again()` function, you will need to exit the function somehow. You can either add a `break` statement to exit the while loop (which will then exit the function) or you could also replace the `break` with a `return` statement.

Comment: The important bit is to `strip()` the result of `input()`, since some platforms include the final newline.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: huh!  I was pretty sure that the stripping was cross-platform, and that was how I read the docs for input as well.  Which ones preserve it?

Comment: Still does not work. I edited the question to provide the whole code, maybe that'll be of help?

Comment: @DSM You are right that the docs explicitly say it's stripping the trailing newline.  However, I've definitely seen the newline being included on Windows XP.  Maybe that was just a bug in some older version of Python?

Comment: Your full code structure is not ideal, but you were missing a `break` statement to get you out of the `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered:

As @Strinnityk said, I added a break below the load_game() and it produced the desired result:

```
positive = ["yes", "y"] 
negative = ["no", "n"]

while True:
    answer = input("Play again? [Y(es) / N(o)]: ").lower().strip()

    if answer in positive:
        ship_points = load_game(game_board)
        break
    elif answer in negative:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()
```